# What happens when $\beta_1 + \beta_2=1$ and when $0<\beta_1 + \beta_2<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following example of the Scwarz-Christoffel integral formula:

$$S(z)=\int_0^z w^{-\beta_1}(1-w)^{-\beta_2}dw$$

with $0<β_1 <1, 0<β_2 <1$, and $1<β_1 +β_2 <2$ and I know that by the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Suppose S(z) is the Schwarz-Christoffel formula (the general one).
>
> (i) If  $\sum_{k=1}^n β_k = 2$, and $P$ denotes the polygon whose
>   vertices are given (in order) by $a_1,...,a_n$ , then $S$ maps the
>   real axis onto $P−{a_∞}$.  The point $a_∞$ lies on the segment
>   $[a_n,a_1]$ and is the image of the point at infinity. Moreover, the
>   (interior) angle at the vertex $a_k$ is $α_kπ$ where $α_k = 1 − β_k$.
>
> (ii) There is a similar conclusion when $1 < \sum_{k=1}^n β_k <2$,
>   except now the image of the extended line is the polygon of $n + 1$
>   sides with vertices $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n, a_∞$. The ang le at the
>   vertex $a_∞$ is $α_∞π$ with $α_∞=1-\beta_∞$ where
>   $\beta_∞=2-\sum_{k=1}^n β_k$

That the above example maps $H$ (upper half plane) to a triangle whose vertices are the images of $0, 1$, and $∞$, and with angles $α_1π, α_2π$, and $α_3π$, where $α_j + β_j = 1$ and $β_1 + β_2 + β_3 = 2$, Am I right?.

The thing is that the above result doesn't take care of the the situation $\beta_1 + \beta_2=1$ and when $0<\beta_1 + \beta_2<1$ in my above example, So Can someone help me with these issues please?

I think I can proceed as follows  [image]
[image]

The thing is that  is not clear for my specific function how to manipulate because for example we have the following

$$S(1)=\int_0^1 w^{-\beta_1}(1-w)^{-\beta_2}dw$$

That it's like a beta function but I don't know which change of variables or how to transform that in a truly beta function and when $z$ is not $1$ how can I apply the method I have said above ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close to $w=0$ the integrand is $\sim \frac{1}{w^{\beta_1}}$. Since the integral $\int_0^{z} \frac{{\rm d}w}{w^\beta}$ diverges when $\beta \geq 1$ and so does the original integral. Considering the integrand close to $w=1$ you can show that the integral also diverges if $\beta_2 \geq 1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? How did you figure that out ? :)

Comment: I did a series expansion of the (second term of the) integrand close to $w=0$: $f(w) = \frac{1}{w^{\beta_1}}\left(1 + \beta_2 w + O(w^{2})\right)$. Because of this for a small $\epsilon > 0$ your integral over $[0,\epsilon]$ is very close to the integral $\int_0^\epsilon \frac{dw}{w^{\beta_1}}$ so if this latter one diverges so does your integral.

Comment: Ok just a second to get the idea :)

Comment: Now, why does it means to this integral to diverge? I mean, which polygon do you get?

Comment: May be I should edit my post so just a second

Comment: Ready the post is edited

Comment: @Winther what do you think?

Comment: I don't have much more to contribute (not really an expert on that polygon stuff it's related to). My comments above was solely directed at what happens to the integral you have when $\beta_1,\beta_2$ does not satisfy $\beta_1+\beta_2\in (1,2)$. What I can say is that your final integral is indeed the $\beta$-function (by definition) $\beta(1-\beta_1,1-\beta_2) = \frac{\Gamma(1-\beta_1)\Gamma(1-\beta_2)}{\Gamma(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)}$.

Comment: Oh I will like to see those computations :) please

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function Just define $x - 1 =-\beta_1$ and $y-1 =-\beta_2$ and your integral becomes the definition of the $\beta$-function $\beta(x,y) = \beta(1-\beta_1,1-\beta_2)$. From the $\Gamma$-function form of the $\beta$-function you can see that it diverges for $\beta_1 = 1$ or $\beta_2 = 1$ or when $\beta_1+\beta_2=2$ since $\Gamma(x)$ diverges as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Good so let me check them if I have questions can I tell you ?

Comment: Yes no problem.

Comment: Right but just give me some time right :) and I'll send you a comment

Answer (score 3):

When $\beta_1+\beta_2<1$ then the upper half plane is mapped onto an infinite truncated sector (a sector with the tip cut off). The apex angle of the sector is $(1-\beta_1-\beta_2)\pi$. When $\beta_1+\beta_2=1$ then the upper half plane is mapped onto half a strip with a slanted edge (an infinite strip cut in two at an angle).

Comment: How did you figure out that ? Is because I am stuck with the computations :)

Comment: The three segments of the real line are mapped to straight line segments. The external angles between these segments at the images of $0$ and $1$ are $\beta_1\pi$ and $\beta_2\pi$ respectively. Then sketch drawings of what you get based on this for different values of $\beta_1+\beta_2$.

Comment: Ok and how did you computed the integral ?

Comment: Don't have to. It suffices to see how $S(z)$ behaves near $0$ and $1$ (basically as $z^{1-\beta_1}$ and $(1-z)^{1-\beta_2}$) and that the argument of any branch of the integrand is constant on real segments.

Comment: Ok just a second to get the idea 

Comment: I am back, I don't get the constant part of the integral, how is that ?

Comment: What about infinity? We have to check infinity right?

Comment: Maybe ,I should edit my post right ? So just give a second

Comment: Ready the post is edited

Comment: Then what do you think?

Comment: The three segments that you are saying are the following from $(- \infty , 0]$, $[0,1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ right?

Comment: Sorry can you provide an image or describe better the figures in your answer is because I can't imagine them thanks in advance

Comment: See [these](http://www.sketchtoy.com/67070862) sketches.

Comment: Ok let me check just a second

Comment: Good so why do you have three angles? since we only have 2 parameters

Comment: [Added](http://www.sketchtoy.com/67070937) $\beta$ parameters in both cases.

Comment: Good so can tell me again how did you figure this out in detail with out computing the integral ? Sorry for this question but is not obvious for me :) thanks in advance

Comment: So how did you do it ? Thanks

Comment: How did you know that we have three line segments ? I mean that the three divisions of the real line are three straight segments

Comment: So what do you say ?